# xPath is working for the last page but not the first - Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I want to extract some data from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=(%222018.01.01%22[Date+-+Publication]+%3A+%223000%22[Date+-+Publication])) using Selenium in Java

The problem is that the xPath `/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[5]/div[" + i + "]/div[2]/p/a` to get every article's title on the page and click on them, works for the last page but not for the first page and I couldn't understand why.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[5]/div[" + i + "]/div[2]/p/a")).click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is an *off-by-one error* as XPath's indexing starts with 1 and having `div[0]` there would not match anything.

In general, though, *your expression is very fragile* as it is an absolute expression with the path starting with the very root of the HTML tree down to the desired element going through every parent. Any minor layout change would break it.

Instead, we could seriously simplify the expression:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'rslt')]/p/a
```

this would match all 20 links per page.

Or, if you prefer more concise CSS selectors:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".rslt > p > a"));
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this now and let you know if it works. But the thing is xPath was more convenient like that because then I simply could put a variable in between and loop it on the page. Otherwise how could I click on each link and check the content and navigate back? Well I can just get links though just came up to my mind.

Comment: @AndréYuhai yeah, I understand your confusion. You could use `findElements` to find multiple elements and then loop over them one by one and click. Or, first gather the `href` values with `getAttribute()` and visit them after.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did now. Got the links into a list and then loop through the list. By the way can we do something like ".class1 .class2 > h1" for cssSelector?

Comment: @AndréYuhai yeah, that's a valid CSS selector.

Comment: I wanted to select that h1 tag using the selector I showed you but this also throws an error. http://prntscr.com/lv6yvk